# System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException: The directory name is invalid

Tags: c#

I am trying to export the event log using the following

```
private static void ExportEventLogs(string exportPath, string Log)
    {
        var ela = new EventLogSession();
        try
        {
            ela.ExportLogAndMessages(Log, PathType.LogName, "*", exportPath + ".evtx", false, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            // weird error direcoty invalid ?????
        }
        catch (EventLogException e)
        {
            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(e.ToString());
        }

    }
```

and calling it here it should create a Directory from the computer name on the current users profile and add the computername + logname to that directory

```
 ExportEventLogs(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\Desktop\\" + System.Environment.MachineName + "\\" + System.Environment.MachineName, "Application");
```

The problem I am getting is The Director Name is Invalid but it creates the correct file, any ideas as to why? I have also tried running the code as an administrator same results

```
 System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException: The directory name is invalid
 at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException.Throw(Int32 errorCode)
 at         System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.NativeWrapper.EvtArchiveExportedLog(EventLogHandle session, String logFilePath, Int32 locale, Int32 flags)
 at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession.ExportLogAndMessages(String path,  PathType pathType, String query, String targetFilePath, Boolean tolerateQueryErrors, CultureInfo targetCultureInfo)
 at Log_Utility.MainWindow.ExportEventLogs(String exportPath, String Log) in c:\Users\Chris.Ondrovic\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Log Utility\Log Utility\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 156
```

Comment: You have `System.Environment.MachineName` twice in that argument to `ExportEventLogs` - is that as designed?

Comment: yes designed it creates a folder of the computer name then attaches creates the file with the prefix of the computer name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied and pasted your code into a fresh program and didn't get an invalid directory name.  I did have to make sure that directory exists before exporting though.  My suggestion would be to look at the exportPath and make sure it doesn't contain any invalid characters.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who look at this and still can't figure out what is going on when this error happens - I found the solution.

After seeing this error when attempting to export Application System logs, I decided to run VS as an Admin, and saw that LocaleMetaData folder is being created along with the file, under that same path you specify. This is the folder it's trying to save information to and depending on where you're saving, you may need administrator privileges.

It's unfortunate the exception message doesn't tell you what's going on because I was scratching my when I saw the file was being created yet still getting an exception.

Comment: This saved me a lot of effort. But I'm puzzled. The `targetFilePath` specifies a folder (`c:\Temp`) that does not require admin privileges. Why should admin privileges be required to create & write to `c:\Temp\LocaleMetaData`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "PathType.LogName" use "PathType.FilePath"
LogName is used for specifying the name of the log like "Application" or "Security"

looks to me are passing in the file path