# Exporting application event logs

Tags: c#, event-log

I ran into a problem when exporting windows application event logs. I used code from msdn.

```
try
      {
          EventLogSession els = new EventLogSession();
          els.ExportLogAndMessages("Application", PathType.LogName, "*", 
              Path.Combine(temporaryDirectory, "ApplicationLogs.evtx"), false, 
                 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
      }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unauthorized access to event logs. "+e.Message);
            }
            catch (EventLogNotFoundException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Event logs not found. "+e.Message);
            }
            catch (EventLogException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Event log exception. "+e.Message);
            }
```

When I start the program, the code runs fine on my computer. However when used on some different computers I sometimes get exception  "Event log exception. The directory name is invalid". The evtx file is exported correctly, however the LocaleMetadata folder that contains .MTA file is not present and the exception is thrown. I've tried searching the internet for solution but couldn't find any. The exported log file is to be viewed on different computer so my understanding is that I need the metadata file exported as well. How can I ensure that the locale metadata folder is always exported alongside evtx file without throwing said exception?

Comment: How are you generating "temporaryDirectory" as this would seem to be your downfall

Comment: string temporaryDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "DarAppTemp"); I create a temporary folder, to which I copy files I need and then zip them together. The temporary directory path is arbitrary, just a place to put things in and dispose of it later.

Comment: Do you make sure "DarAppTemp" actually exists before exporting?

Comment: string temporaryDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "DarAppTemp");
            if (Directory.Exists(temporaryDirectory))
            {
                Directory.Delete(temporaryDirectory, true);
            }
            Directory.CreateDirectory(temporaryDirectory); Directory should be present by time I'm trying to copy files into it. Other files are present without problem, just ExportLogAndMessages method seems to throw this exception on some machines.

Comment: Do those machines (where it fails) have something in common that the others don't?

Comment: That I don't know. It failed on one virtual machine but on other one and my work station it didn't. I'm sorry That I cannot give you more information about this. Do you, perhaps, know of some other way to save windows event logs with its metadata?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37661242/468523). It works if you run the program as Admin. As to why that should be, I do not know.